# How to execute event from another event?

Tags: .net, events, datagridview

I have a dategridview. It has UserDeletingRow event

```
private void dataGridVWTransactions_UserDeletingRow(
  object sender,
  DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
{

   DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show(
      "Do you want delete selected transaction?",
      "Warning",
      MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);

     if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
     {
        e.Cancel = true;
     }
 }
```

I want to call this Event from toolstripbutton control.

What must i Do?How can I do this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "call" this event? Do you want to delete the row and thus trigger the event, or just execute that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to display a confirmation while deleting a row from Grid as well as User selects a row and press delete toolstrip button?

Instead of calling the event from Button, make the confirmation an another method and call it from two places.

Try this code

```
private bool ShowConfirm()
{
DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show(
      "Do you want delete selected transaction?",
      "Warning",
      MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);

     return dr == DialogResult.Cancel;
}
```

And in the GridView delete event

```
e.Cancel = ShowConfirm();
```

And in the Button

```
if(ShowConfirm())
{
//Do something
}
```